# How to split a list that has ONLY ONE integer value in Python?

Tags: python, list, split, arr

I want to split a value in a list and make it two values.

```
arr = [10]
```

The array should turn in to:

```
arr = [1,0]
```

Comment: It's different because it is not in a string and I am supposed to solve this wihout a builtin function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension with two iterations:

```
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for y in arr for x in str(y)]
[1, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to split up an integer in the format like this, you can use `str()` to
make the integer into its parts.

You would need to do this on just the variable not, the list.
So

`num = arr[0]`

and then turn this into a string

`string = str(num)`

which you can turn into an list with `list()`

And then you would turn the multiple strings back into numbers with `int()`

So all together:

```
>>> arr = [10]
>>> num = arr[0]
>>> string = str(num)
>>> string_arr = list(string)
>>> arr = list(map(int, string_arr))
>>> arr
[1,0]
```

Or simplified down instead of using intermediate variables.

```
>>> arr = [10]
>>> arr = list(map(int, str(arr[0])))
>>> arr
[1,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by using map, list, converting to string, list comprehension.

If your list has only one value.

**Python 2**

```py
arr = [10]
arr = map(int,str(arr[0]))
```

**Python 3**

```py
arr = [10]
arr = list(map(int, str(arr[0])))
```

**Both for python 2 and 3**

```py
arr = [10]
arr_str=list(str(arr[0]))
arr = [int(x) for x in arr_str]
```

one Liner

```py
arr = [10]
arr = [int(x) for x in list(str(arr[0]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a list comprehension:

```
[int(digit) for digit in str(arr[0])]
```

Or `list(map())`:

```
list(map(int, str(arr[0])))
```

For the most efficient solution, don't convert to a string; instead, use basic math operations:

```
import math

[arr[0] // 10 ** n % 10 for n in reversed(range(int(math.log10(arr[0])) + 1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to keep dividing the given integer by 10 and yielding the remainder until the quotient becomes 0, and then reverse the resulting list to obtain the desired list:

```
def split_int(i):
    while True:
        i, r = divmod(i, 10)
        yield r
        if not i:
            break
```

so that `list(split_int(arr[0]))[::-1]` returns:

```
[1, 0]
```